# ANGULAR error : 'app-header' is not a known element:

Tags: angular

DESIRED STRUCTURE and WORKING STRUCTURE in IMAGE below please see it first.

[folder+componet+module structure and imports details IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaQUt.png)

**ERROR:**

```
ERROR in app/layouts/homepage/homepage.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'app-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

1 <app-header></app-header>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  app/layouts/homepage/homepage.component.ts:10:16
    10   templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I don't want to import (SharedModule)shared.module.ts in app.module.ts, just want SharedModule in the modules where it has been used (homepage.module.ts + addNewUser.module.ts ).

### checked:

List item

1. imported and exported  HeaderComponent (header.component.ts) in shared.module.ts
2. imported  (SharedModule)shared.module.ts in both homepage.module.ts + addNewUser.module.ts
3. imported HomepageModule + AddNewUserModule in app.module.ts
4. restarted CLI + PC

using angular 9

Comment: do not include unnecessary modules

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved,
  my mistakes

1. not imported HomepageComponent in homepage.module.ts
2. not exported HomepageComponent from homepage.module.ts

I have this help anyone in need.

Answer (score 2):

I kept running into this in my tests.  My tests kept failing even though the application worked fine.  I went round it for several days before figuring out that when you are using components from other modules you also need to import them into the *.spec.ts file

```
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import { SharedModule } from "./shared/shared.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

describe("AppComponent", () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, SharedModule],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it("should create the app", () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
```